# Angular *ngFor Howto stack element tag with left and right on respective sides?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

[Expected left to be stacked top left and right top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qFlF.jpg)

[Need to stack elements with name left in left side and right in right side
Using single *ngFor div/ ul /table any means .....
Sample play around provided below]
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-index-example-wntaie?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You could add class based on condition.

So with your stackblitz example I would write it like this.

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let course of courses; index as i">
  <div [ngClass]="{'leftsec': courses[i].name == 'left',
  'rightsec': courses[i].name == 'right'}">
    {{course.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this approach , but could find solution to stack each on left and right ends , could someone kindly fork and share a solution?

Comment: @Rahul is it just the css what you are missing? The rest of you stackblitz looks okay.

Comment: Yes Css , issue , i tried many methods

Comment: any available , solutions for this

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @Rahul Krishnakumar!
Since we speak about list items, you can try this solution.

P.S accidently I just saved it to your stackblitz. Sorry about that.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-index-example-b2ysbk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
<div>
  <ul>
  <li
    *ngFor="let course of courses; index as i"
    [ngClass]="courses[i].name == 'left' ? 'leftsec' : 'rightsec'"
  >
    {{ courses[i].name + ' ' + courses[i].id }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the styling

```
.leftsec {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.rightsec {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 16em;
}

li {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Hi ,that's okay ,** but while adding more elements with left and rightvalues,   its not stacking properly.**      please refer below link,                                                                                              [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-index-example-m11k71?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Rahul, https://i.postimg.cc/vZX6Crf0/lists.png . Maybe its depends from the screen. That is how its looks like by me. If you want more elements, you could change the height property of the <ul> right now it is 16 rem. P.S If my answer helps you, could you vote about it ? Thank you

Comment: Hey @DeanTwit - this solution only works for <= 10 items because it relies on 
`height: 16em;` set on the ul

Comment: Hey @DonaldDuck , of course it did.  This is exactly what was asked. Ofc, it could be done much more elegantly, working on all devices, but I think it's just as well for a beginner to put some effort in that direction, and regarding height , you can read more about the relative units here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units .  REM is based on the font-size. So, 16 rem ofc will be different in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-index-example-jkkeue?file=app/app.component.html

You had the right idea with using `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`

I added a getter for leftCourses and rightCourses to clean up the code a bit.